# openerp server action - python code

Tags: python, odoo

i dont know if i should be asking this here (im now thinking maybe a moderator would move it to stackoverflow), but im not getting an answer on the openerp or launchpad forums.
In OpenERP 6.0.1, the following function does what its supposed to do when a button is placed in the invoice form to execute it:

```
class account_invoice(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    """ Function to update all lines on invoice """
    def update_invoice(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        line_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
        invoice_ids = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
        for invoice in invoice_ids:
            for line in invoice.invoice_line:
                if line.product_id:
                    res = line_obj.product_id_change(cr, uid, [line.id], (line.product_id and line.product_id.id or False), uom=(line.uos_id and line.uos_id.id or False), qty=(line.quantity or 0),
                name=(line.name or ''), type=(invoice.type or False), partner_id=invoice.partner_id.id, fposition_id=invoice.fiscal_position.id, price_unit=(line.price_unit or 0),
                address_invoice_id=(invoice.address_invoice_id and invoice.address_invoice_id.id or False), currency_id=(invoice.currency_id and invoice.currency_id.id or False), context=context)
                    price_unit = res['value']['price_unit']
                    discount = res['value']['discount']
                    line_obj.write(cr, uid, [line.id], {'price_unit': price_unit})
                    line_obj.write(cr, uid, [line.id], {'discount': discount})
        return True

    account_invoice()
```

this is to say that the invoice lines' price unit and discount are updated when this button is clicked in the form.

im trying to create a server action for object "Invoice" of type "python code" that executes this function on all invoices from a menu item. in the python code box, i wrote:

```
inv = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
line_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
for invoice in inv.browse(cr, uid, ids):
    for line in invoice.invoice_line:
        res = line_obj.product_id_change(cr, uid, [line.id], (line.product_id and line.product_id.id or False), uom=(line.uos_id and line.uos_id.id or False), qty=(line.quantity or 0), name=(line.name or ''), type=(invoice.type or False), partner_id=invoice.partner_id.id, fposition_id=invoice.fiscal_position.id, price_unit=(line.price_unit or 0), address_invoice_id=(invoice.address_invoice_id and invoice.address_invoice_id.id or False), currency_id=(invoice.currency_id and invoice.currency_id.id or False), context=context)
    price_unit = res['value']['price_unit']
    discount = res['value']['discount']
    line_obj.write(cr, uid, [line.id], {'price_unit': price_unit})
    line_obj.write(cr, uid, [line.id], {'discount': discount})
```

but it does not work. what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
can anyone help me write a function that updates all invoices' lines' similar to those in /account/wizard/account_invoice_state.py ?

Comment: can you be more precise on the "it does not work" part?

Comment: well if i had made mistakes in syntax, i would get an error accordingly when double clicking the menu item. now it doesnt cause an error, so its being executed only the invoices dont change. as if the function is being executed in the wrong place and not being applied to any actual invoice. hope im clear enough

Comment: @3a2roub: What kind of debugging have you applied? You can trace the function to check what's wrong using output functionality like `print` if possible or GUI interaction.

Comment: @NiklasB. The only way to get some debugging of whats happening is to use the debug_sql log level in the GUI and as u know that would leave a significantly long output for a single click. no errors are shown however, maybe it would be easier for someone to try to convert the function `update_invoice` that actually works from within a form via button, to a server action of type python code. im sure mine is flawed in a way!  
i think i just need the proper syntax to apply those few lines to all lines on all invoices.

Comment: Your function is called when you press the button?

Comment: @Lafada: yes in the first scenario, a button is placed inside the invoice form (even works on the tree view) and the function is executed when the button is pressed. im tying in a different direction now, creating an action similar to the "Confirm Invoices" action but having a hard time figuring out the proper syntax. i cant seem to execute the function on all invoice lines of all invoices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to successfully write what i need, here it is:

```
class account_invoice_update(osv.osv_memory):

_name = "account.invoice.update"

""" Function to update all lines on selected invoice(s) """
def invoice_update(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    pool_obj = pooler.get_pool(cr.dbname)
    data_inv = pool_obj.get('account.invoice').read(cr, uid, context['active_ids'], ['state'], context=context)

    for record in data_inv:
        if record['state'] in ('cancel','paid','open'):
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning'), _("Selected Invoice(s) cannot be cancelled as they are already in 'Cancelled','Done', or 'Open' state!"))

    inv_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
    inv_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
    for invoice in inv_obj.browse(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'), context=context):
        for line in invoice.invoice_line:
            res = inv_line_obj.product_id_change(cr, uid, [line.id], (line.product_id and line.product_id.id or False), uom=(line.uos_id and line.uos_id.id or False), qty=(line.quantity or 0), name=(line.name or ''), type=(invoice.type or False), partner_id=invoice.partner_id.id, fposition_id=invoice.fiscal_position.id, price_unit=(line.price_unit or 0), address_invoice_id=(invoice.address_invoice_id and invoice.address_invoice_id.id or False), currency_id=(invoice.currency_id and invoice.currency_id.id or False), context=context)
            price_unit = res['value']['price_unit']
            discount = res['value']['discount']
            inv_line_obj.write(cr, uid, [line.id], {'price_unit': price_unit})
            inv_line_obj.write(cr, uid, [line.id], {'discount': discount})

    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}

account_invoice_update()
```

Comment: What is `pooler` and how did you define it? Did you import it? Or is it a global variable that you have assigned with something else?

Answer (score 1):

If I want to run some code on the selected rows in a screen, I use a wizard with `client_action_multi`. Here's [a wizard I wrote](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/main/view/2972/promise_date/wizard/wizard_sanity_checked.py) that just sets a "sanity checked" flag on stock pickings:

```
import wizard
import pooler

def _set_flags(self, cr, uid, data, context):
    stock_picking_obj = pooler.get_pool(cr.dbname).get('stock.picking')

    move_ids = data['ids']
    picking_ids = stock_picking_obj.search(
        cr,
        uid,
        [('move_lines', 'in', move_ids)])
    stock_picking_obj.write(cr, uid, picking_ids, {'sanity_checked': True})
    return {}

class sanity_checked(wizard.interface):
    states = {
        'init': {
            'actions': [_set_flags],
            'result': {'type': 'state', 'state':'end'}
        },
    }
sanity_checked('promise.date.sanity.checked')
```

I [configure the wizard](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/main/view/2972/promise_date/stock_view.xml#L210) with the `client_action_multi` so it can be executed on the selected records in a list:

```
<wizard
        id="wiz_sanity_checked"
        model="stock.move"
        string="Sanity Checked"
        name="promise.date.sanity.checked"
        keyword="client_action_multi"/>
```

To actually run the wizard, click the Action button in the menubar.

Answer (score 0):

In server action you can write simple python codes.. You are trying to use self.pool.get(). Its not possible from server action.And please be specific about your requirement

Comment: I realized that which is why i focused on writing a function similar to the function: **invoice_confirm** in **account_invoice_state.py** and hence executing the function from the **actions**. now its just a matter of properly modifying the function **update_invoice** mentioned above, which is where im stuck. should i post the example function that im trying to sort of mimic?